# Flash and Action Script Questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I ask Flash CS4 and Action Script programming related questions at StackOverflow.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not - it's all programming. Has anyone suggested you shouldn't?

In particular, see the [actionscript3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript3), [actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) and [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) tags.

Comment: No actually I want to add a preloader in a flash file. So this question includes the Adobe Flash interaction as well as Action Script programming, so I thought may be SO will close my post due to, not a programming related (caz flash generally comes in graphic designing). So it is OK to ask this type of question there?

Comment: I just wanna confirm, so i thought before posting I should use SO meta for permission :)

Answer (score 0):

People ask AS questions all the time on StackOverflow.